# A question regarding the Vector Space containing all functions with derivatives of all orders

Tags: derivatives

$Statement\;Of\;The\;Problem\;That\;Provoked\;The\;Question\;:$ Let  $V$ be the vector space of functions which have derivatives of all orders, and let $D: V\rightarrow V$ be the derivative. What is the kernel of $D$?

$My\;Question:$ Shouldn't this be the kernel of D then be the space of all constants? I believe my reasoning is sound in that as constant functions technically have derivatives of all orders, and the only function type with a derivative of zero is a constant, that should hold. It seems like an easy one, but it seems a little too easy. Is my reasoning valid?

Edit 1: Word change to denote that the attention is being restricted to the Kernel of $D$.

Comment: What's the domain of the functions in $V$?

Comment: Lang sets the convention that the field for any vector space is either the Complex or the Reals. However, given the past context, I'm confining any analysis to just the Reals for now.

Comment: If $V$ is the space of smooth real functions on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, then the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}-1, & x<0\\1, & x>0\end{cases}$ is in the kernel.

Comment: @Johnq But I didn't ask what's the field of scalars for this vector space.

Comment: @littleO : I apologize, but I'm a bit confused. Wouldn't the domain draw from the field that V is a vector space over?

Comment: In any case, the domain is not specified by the author.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy : To clarify then, it would be overall the set of functions with fixed values only? Also, how did you see that? I follow the reasoning behind it, but don't think I would be able to come up with something like that. Did it just come to you, or was there some way that you looked at it specifically?

Comment: In my case it is just experience. It is a classical textbook problem. But when you try to prove your claim you might notice it. To prove that the function is constant you need to integrate. Then you manage to prove that the value of the function at the end of the integral is equal to that at the beginning.  But to do that you need to be able to reach from one point to the other within the domain using the path of integration.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy : So if I'm understanding right, you're working backwards? Starting from the fact that the derivative is zero you find that the function must have constant values. But, it's not necessarily one constant if you blow holes in your domain and define your function such that it's differentiable on all intervals where the domain is continuous?

Comment: To try to make my earlier point more clearly, I think the vector space $V$ has not been defined precisely enough.  Do you mean that $V = \{ f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ such that $f$ has derivatives of all orders} \}$?  In that case, the kernel of $D$ consists only of constant functions.  However, could it be that $V = \{ f:(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R \text{ such that $f$ has derivatives of all orders} \}$? In that case the kernel of $D$ is more complicated.  We need to know exactly what $V$ is.  If $f \in V$, then what is the domain of $f$?  As it stands, we do not know.

Comment: It was never specified here (even though he specifies the domain explicitly in previous examples). From before context, I took it to be the full Reals, but I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is $\>\geq1$ times differentiable on an open interval $J$ then $Df=0$ implies
$$f(y)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(y-x)=0\qquad\forall \ x,\ y\in J\ ,$$  hence $f$ is constant on $J$. Conversely, if $f$ is constant on $J$ then ($f$ is differentiable and) $Df=0$. It follows that in this situation ${\rm ker}(D)$ is the set of constant functions on $J$, and has dimension $1$.

If $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}$ is an arbitrary open set, i.e.,  a disjoint union of open intervals $\Omega_\iota$ $(\iota\in I)$, then the differentiable functions $f:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ satisfying $Df=0$ on $\Omega$ are only constant on each  $\Omega_\iota\,$: There are values $c_\iota$ (that can be chosen independently) such that 
$$f(x)=c_\iota\qquad\forall x\in\Omega_\iota,\quad\forall\iota\in I\ .$$
In this case the kernel of $D$ consists of these *locally constant* functions, and has dimension $\#I\leq\infty$.